# ASP.net Bar Chart Control - Getting Started

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, charts, background

Almost done my poll web part, yet need to do some modification on my bar chart but couldn't find any related resource online

[image]

I need to remove the numbers `(-1,0,1,2,3...)` from both axes`(x and y)`is that possible?
also I need to remove the default chart's background image, its better if i can switch it with solid white

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disabled Labels**

You can do this by adding **LabelStyle Enabled="false"** as per below

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY>
                <LabelStyle Enabled="false" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX>
                <LabelStyle Enabled="false" />
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

**Change Background**

```
<asp:Chart id="Chart1" runat="server">
  <BorderSkin BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" 
    SkinStyle="Emboss" />
</asp:Chart>
```

**PageColor** & **BackColor** property will help you to change background of chart

**Update :**

update your ChartArea as per below to disable grid lines and make it white

```
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="black" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White"
            BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
            <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                <MajorGrid Enabled="false"></MajorGrid>
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsStartedFromZero="true">
                <MajorGrid Enabled="false"></MajorGrid>
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
```

Comment: `Disabled Labels` works great, and the background changed but i noticed that its not what i want, i might explained my question wrong, i want to replace the grid background of the chart with solid white color, is that achievable?

Comment: That was helpful, it works now, I'm going to accept the answer, if you can notice there still a tiny line parts outside the chart board, is it possible to remove them? Thanks..

Comment: @Rami please add <MajorTickMark Enabled="false" />in both axis section then it will also remove

Comment: yeah i just saw it in the properties pane, thnx